# My program won't seem to recognize spaces in Lua

Tags: lua

Have to make a program for school. Basically you have a string and you need to make it secret by using a code. The secret string is each letter + the secret code in the alphabet. So BALL would be EDOO with the code 3. A space has location zero in the alphabet and if the location + the code is bigger than 26 the new letter is string + code - 26 now whenever I execute my program and add spaces it just "translates" the first part before the space. FYI, the comments next to it are in Dutch and not that important.

```
    local code = 3
local string = string.upper("spaghetti carbonara") --string
local alfabet = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" --alfabet
local lengte = 6 --lengte van string

for getal1 = 1, lengte do   -- for want moet herhaald worden/getal
  local letter = string.sub(string, getal1, getal1) -- letter uit de string halen
  local locatie = string.find(alfabet, letter) -- letter vinden in alfabet
  if locatie + code < 26 then
    locatie2 = locatie + code -- nieuwe locatie vinden met code
  elseif locatie + code > 26 then
    locatie2 = locatie + code - 26
  end
  local letter2 = string.sub(alfabet, locatie2, locatie2) -- letter die overeenkomt met locatie
  io.write(letter2)
end
```

Comment: You have forgotten to change `local lengte = 6` to the real length.

Comment: Tip: don't name variables using existing names. `string` is a lua library, you won't be able to use it if you replace it with something else. It works for you here because string can use its functions.

Tip 2: Use #yourstring instead of `lengte`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't be using the variable `string` like you're doing on line 2. That doesn't break your program only by coincidence because all strings have a metamethod with `__index` pointing to `string`. You should rename that variable to something else instead (`text`, `input`, `str`, etc.)

With that out of the way, your program seems to work just fine for me. Adding a bunch of spaces to the input adds a bunch of "C"s to the output. Maybe you've just forgotten to change that `local lengte = 6` to `local lengte = #string`? As it currently is, it will only "translate" the first 6 characters in the string.

---

As a hint on how to improve this: you can replace the whole encryption / decryption part with a single call to `string.gsub` if you pass it a table as its third argument:

```lua
local code = {}
code["a"] = "b"
code["b"] = "a"

print(string.gsub("abc", ".", code))
-- Prints "bac"
-- "a" gets replaced with "b", as per the table
-- same with "b"
-- "c" does not appear as a key in the table, so it's simply ignored
```

Then all you need to do is build a table that maps every character you want to replace to what you want to replace it with, which is a bit easier to achieve:

```lua
local function decrypt_encrypt_dictionaries(alphabet, offset)
   local encrypt, decrypt = {}, {}
   -- Code that fills the two tables goes here :D
   return encrypt, decrypt
end

local ROT13_encrypt, ROT13_decrypt = dectypt_encrypt_dictionaries("abcde"--[[...and so on]], 13)

local some_text = io.read()
-- Encrypt some text:
local encrypted = string.gsub(some_string, ".", ROT13_encrypt)
-- Decrypt it again:
local original = string.gsub(encrypted, ".", ROT13_decrypt)
-- See if it's the same:
print(original)
```

As I mentioned above, this only shifts the difficulty from the encryption/decryption to building the two Lua tables, which I'm leaving for you to figure out.

Comment: Thank you so much for the in dept reply. I can really learn from this, my Lua is still basic but seeing a comment like this helps me a lot. I will change it in my program. Thanks!